# Is there a good way to access batch id in pytorch datasets using dataloaders?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

In pytorch datasets, the way to access individual samples is given by implementing the `__getitem__` method, but there seems to me that there are no natural way to get the batch id for the extracted sample. One may argue that batch ids should be handled outside the dataset (e.g. in training loops or similar), but I want to modify the processing of the sample when it is retrieved based on the batch id.

I have a hacked solution given below, but I am wondering if there are better ways of doing this.

The "solution" below doesn't work when using `num_workers` > 1, so it is non-functional.

```
from typing import List, Tuple, Iterator
from torch.utils.data import RandomSampler, Dataset, DataLoader, BatchSampler


class intwithbtx(int):
    def __new__(cls, theint: int, btx: int):
        x = int.__new__(cls, theint)
        x.btx_number = btx
        return x


class IdBatchSampler(BatchSampler):
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[List[int]]:
        batch = []
        iii = 0
        for idx in self.sampler:
            batch.append(intwithbtx(idx, iii))
            if len(batch) == self.batch_size:
                yield batch
                iii += 1
                batch = []
        if len(batch) > 0 and not self.drop_last:
            yield batch


class RangeDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, lgt: int):
        self.data = list(range(lgt))

    def __getitem__(self, item: intwithbtx):
        dt = self.data[item] + item.btx_number*1000
        return dt

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ds = RangeDataset(30)
    smp = IdBatchSampler(RandomSampler(range(len(ds))), batch_size=3, drop_last=False)
    loader = DataLoader(ds, batch_sampler=smp)
    for btx in loader:
        print(btx)
    loader2 = DataLoader(ds, batch_sampler=smp, num_workers=2)  # Fails.
    for btx in loader2:
        print(btx)
```